# Loops and Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This code should create 20 arrays, each with a different mutation, and store the 20 arrays within another array, 'mutations'. Problem is, it outputs

```
[ [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ],
  [ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ] ]
```

In other words, it only changes one number and then iterates that one change 20 times. If possible, I would like to make it so that each iteration, the mutation is stored, and then the succeeding iteration builds upon the initial mutation of the array. Like this:

`[ 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]` -> `[ 0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]` -> `[ 0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]` - so you can see, subtle changes every time.

Here is the code as it stands:

```
function concestor2() {
    this.genome = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // the code to be scrambled
    this.replicability = 10;
}

var venutian = new concestor2();
venutian.scramble = parseInt(Math.random() * 10); //picks random number 1-10
venutian.scramble2 = venutian.scramble;

function scrambler(P1) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 20; ++i) {
        P1.genome[P1.scramble] = P1.scramble2; //selects random element of array
    }

    return P1.genome;
}

scrambler(venutian);

var mutations = []; // array to store the 20 mutations from the loop

function createVariables() {
    for (var j = 0; j <= 20; ++j) {
        mutations[j] = scrambler(venutian);
    }

    return mutations;
}

createVariables();
console.log(venutian.genome)
console.log(mutations)
```

Comment: Can you clarify, is each mutation performed on the original `this.genome` or on the previous "mutation"? You words seem to suggest on the original, but your example suggests on the previous?

Comment: Also your "random" picks a number between 0 and 9, not 1 and 10

Comment: the this.genome is just a dummy that is mutated every time. The important part is logging the result of each mutation to the 'mutations' array. And the random number thing is irrelevant, but thanks for pointing it out, I guess. I keep changing the code and getting odd results but never quite what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

Javascript

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function getMutations(obj) {
    var mutations = [],
        last = obj.genome.length - 1,
        mutation,
        count,
        value,
        pos;

    for (count = 0; count <= 20; count += 1) {
        pos = getRandomInt(0, last);
        mutation = obj.genome.slice();
        mutation[pos] = getRandomInt(0, 9);
        mutations.push(mutation);
    }

    return mutations;
}

function concestor2() {
    this.genome = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; // the code to be scrambled
    this.replicability = 10;
}

var venutian = new concestor2();

console.log(getMutations(venutian));
```

Example output

```
[
    [6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 9],
    [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    [1, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/42KFg/)

Comment: very clever, and close to what I'm looking for. I'll tweak it from here and see where it goes

Answer (score 0):

Why do scramble and scramble2 have the exact same value? Don't you want to use 2 different random numbers. Also you may want to create new random numbers each time scrambler is being called.
And createVariables probably should look like this

```
function createVariables() {
    mutations[0] = scrambler(venutian);
    for (var j = 1; j <= 20; ++j) {
        mutations[j] = scrambler(mutations[j-1]);
    }
    return mutations;
}
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't think before I made the assignment

Comment: when you say create new random numbers each time, do you mean I should create the random numbers within the scrambler for loop? because the main problem is just the repeated iteration of the first random assignment